# Google Mock - private conversion operator int

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am using a similar code based on the following example:

```
class FOO
{
private:
    operator int() const;
};

class BARMOCK
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(Bar, void(const FOO& foo));
};
```

Unfortunately the following error message is generated by the compiler:

```
gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h(892): error C2248: 'FOO::operator int': cannot access private member declared in class 'FOO'
```

which comes from gtest-internal itself:

```
static const bool value = sizeof(Helper(ImplicitlyConvertible::MakeFrom())) == 1;
```

Is there any possible way to make it work, or is it a known limitation of the google mock framework?

Of course there are ways to workaround the problem, like:

```
class BARMOCK
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(BarMock, void());
    void Bar(const FOO& foo) { BarMock(); }
};
```

But this is just a workaround, not a real solution. Does anyone know anything about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that googlemock wants to print your FOO values. And it behaves according to  this algorithm:

1. If you have defined function `PrintTo(FOO const&, std::ostream*)` then it is used
2. Otherwise, if it is possible to print via classic C++ way (with `operator <<`) then it is used
3. Otherwise, the bytes that represents this FOO object are printed

In your case C++ compiler (not googlemock) is "fooled" by your private int cast operator - `int` is printable - so `std::cout << FOO{}` is printable - but - then compiler notices that this conversion is private...

So:

1. Either defined `PrintTo(FOO const&, std::ostream*)`
2. Or define `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const FOO&)` - this operator might be defined as friend function,

like:

```
class FOO {
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const FOO& foo)
  {
      return os << static_cast<int>(foo);
  }
```